# Is there a method of analytically solving the expected value of this random variable?

Tags: expected-value, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have the following loss function L where $S_{t}$ represents the price at time t and follows a Geometric Brownian motion. $S_0$ and $r$ are constants.

$$
L = \frac{\sqrt{r}\frac{S_{t}}{S_{o}}-1}{\frac{S_{t}}{S_{o}}+1}
$$

I am now trying to find $E[L]$ (the expected value of L). I know it's possible to solve this problem using a Monte Carlo simulation but I was wondering if there was an analytical solution. I think I have to find the pdf of $L$ and since [we know the pdf of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion#Properties) $S_t$, I believe it shouldn't be hard to figure out but I'm not sure how to go about it.